AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest' with sha256
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from hashlib import sha256

def produce_digest_char_by_char(word):
    d=sha256();print(d.hexdigest())
    for b in word:
        #d=d.update(b.encode()):print(d.hexdigest())#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'
        d.update(b.encode());print(d.hexdigest())#This works fine
    return d.hexdigest()


print(sha256().hexdigest())
print(sha256(b"lana").hexdigest())
print(produce_digest_char_by_char("lana"))


The commented out line does not work, giving me this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'. By trial-and-error I figured out what the fix in the  code is but I would like to know why does Python behave this way? help(sha256) gives this info
    Returns a sha256 hash object; optionally initialized with a string

In this info there is nothing written that sha256 may return None.

"In this info there is nothing written that sha256 may return None." - but sha256 isn't returning None. d.update is returning None.

Look at your commented-out line.  You have d, and you call the update method, which returns None.  You then assign it to d, replacing the hashlib object with None.  Why would you do that?  Why did you think you needed to keep assning to d?  Leave it alone,  Your error is essentially a typo (unintended d=).
